# running terminal command from python 3.3

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, terminal, command

i am trying to run wkhtmltopdf (a routine that convert an html to pdf: http://wkhtmltopdf.org) command from python 3.3 (mac osx 10.7.5).

The routine works like a charm when directly run on terminal with the following command:

```
wkhtmltopdf http:google.com /Users/ME/Desktop/google.pdf
```

where http:google.com is the html that will be converted to pdf in the destination file: /Users/ME/Desktop/google.pdf

However when calling the shell from python:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["wkhtmltopdf http:google.com /Users/ME/Desktop/google.pdf"])
```

**i get:**

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in
<module>
    subprocess.call(["wkhtmltopdf http:google.com /Users/thenoze/Desktop/google.pdf"])   File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py",
line 523, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py",
line 824, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py",
line 1448, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wkhtmltopdf http:google.com /Users/ME/Desktop/google.pdf'
```

--> Any lead how to format my subprocess.call() ?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the command line arguments as list items:

```
subprocess.call(["wkhtmltopdf", "http:google.com", "/Users/ME/Desktop/google.pdf"])
```

Otherwise, `wkhtmltopdf ... google.pdf` is treated as a program path, instead of `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: Thank you for looking into that.  

It seems that if i run this directly with python in the terminal window it works perfect.  However when using into a python routine it fails to recognize the 'wkhtmltopdf'.  
I bought it was because the path in terminal is not same as the python one when running as a *.py.  But it did not work either.

What do you think it could be ?